# Angular-CLI 1.2.0 generates code that fails in Android Webview (on certain devices) but angular-cli beta.25 doesn't

Tags: typescript, android-webview, angular-cli, chromium

I have spent several days now tracking down an issue and stripping it down to something reproducible, but I don't understand the underlying technology to make further progress without help. Detailed questions at the bottom of this post.

## Setup

I generate two empty Angular apps with two different versions of angular-cli.  I run these two apps in various configurations (1) native in a browser on (a) desktops, (b) tablets, and (c) set-top boxes.  I also run them (2) in the WebView of an Android app on (b) Android tablets and (c) set-top boxes.

## Results

- CLI-BETA: code generated by angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.25.5

  - browsers (all platforms: cases 1a, 1b, 1c) : OK
  - WebApp on Android tablets (case 2b): OK
  - WebApp on Android set-top boxes (case 2c): OK
- CLI-LATEST: code generated by @angular/cli@1.2.0

  - browsers (all platforms): OK
  - WebApp on Android tablets: OK
  - WebApp on Android set-top box: **FAIL!!**

## Expected Result

The WebApp on set-top box (case 2c:) should run CLI-LATEST as well as (if not better than) CLI-BETA.

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Build two versions of the default Angular app using two versions of Angular-CLI

   ```
   $ npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
   $ npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.25.5
   $ ng --version 
   ...
   angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.25.5
   node: 6.11.0
   os: darwin x64
   $ ng new cli-beta
   $ cd cli-beta
   $ npm install && ng build
   $ cd ..
   $ npm uninstall -g angular-cli
   $ npm install -g @angular/cli@1.2.0
   $ ng --version
   ...
   @angular/cli: 1.2.0
   node: 6.11.0
   os: darwin x64
   $ ng new cli-latest
   $ cd cli-latest
   $ npm install && ng build
   $ cd ..
   ```
2. Run `ng serve` in either directory to verify it runs in a browser. (the newer version shows the Angular logo).
3. Host the two applications somewhere on the web so the Android app can load them onto a WebView.
4. Get sample source code for an [Android App with a WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted)
5. Run App on a tablet (I used a stock Samsung SM-T580)
6. Run on a set-top box (I used Nexbox A95X)

   - Android 6.0.1, Chromium 44,
   - I later upgraded to Chromium 59 (aka [AndroidSystemWebview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en)), but it didn't help.

## Specific Error

Using logcat, I see only.

```
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5706)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined", source: http://some.web.host.com/vendor.bundle.js (5706)
```

Here's the relevant lines in the generated code

```
5705: function combine(options) {
5706:     return ((Object)).assign.apply(((Object)), [{}].concat(options));
5707: }
```

So I can polyfill `Object.assign` and it makes that particular error go away, but it feels like "kicking the can downhill" and not actually solving the problem.   Also CLI-BETA has a nearly identical definition of a combine function.

## Questions I Can't Answer

1. Why does `Object.assign` seem to need a polyfill in this circumstance?
2. If Angular-CLI-1.2 code runs on the Chrome browser on the device, shouldn't it run exactly the same in the WebView activity? (both were upgraded to the latest versions Chromium 59.x.x.x)
3. If I provide a polyfill for `Object.assign`, then I get an error about `Array.from`. I can polyfill that too, then I get

   ```
    chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(37194)] "Uncaught Error: No provider for PlatformRef!", source: http://some.web.host.com/vendor.bundle.js (37194)
   ```

(PlatformRef seems to be a simple JS object/singleton for basic Angular services.) Since that is not a system object, I assume there's no such thing as a polyfill to correct/mask this problem, right?

4. Is this not about the CLI at all, and just a symptom of some underlying thing that's changed? Possibly different versions of TypeScript (~2.0.3 vs ~2.3.3)?

Comment: Update:  2017-09-17.  The issue still exists with angular/cli 1.4.2 and Chromium 61.x.x.x.   Object.assign is an ES6/ES2015 API and it seems WebView on this platform has that crippled somehow.

Comment: Correction: After installing Chromium on the box, it is still loading Chromium 44 inside the WebView. I tested this by loading the site html5test.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see, the problem is that your WebView does not support the `Object.assign` function. Support for the `Object.assign` function is from version 45 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Angular only supports the latest versions of browsers https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

I have a similar problem with the cordova app. I have somehow installed several Android System WebView applications on my phone with different versions (39 and 61). With the cordova application, it uses the older version of WebView 39, although there is a newer version.
I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" with the same relevant lines in the generated code `function combine (options) ...` with `Object.assign` code.

**Therefore, make sure that you do not have another version of WebView installed and that you are using version 59.**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought I had done that, but even after downloading AndroidSystemWebview, the WebView on this device is still loading Chromium 44. I discovered this by loading html5test.com in the WebView.  Is there something special that needs to be done after installing the new WebView to get the system to recognize it, or might this NexBox be broken in some way?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was webview version, I was trying to use webview from emulator and refused and when I used real device I worked perfectly. After doing some research I found that WebView System was the issue